# Is the propositional term $s$ unsatisfiable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If $s \vDash  t \rightarrow u$ and $s \vdash \neg t \rightarrow \neg u$, then is $s$ unsatisfiable?

Let $v$ be a valuation. Then $(v(s) = T \rightarrow v(t)= F \wedge v(u) = T) \land (v(s) = T \rightarrow v(t) = T \lor v(u) = F)$

But I get stuck here?

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. Take $t=u$; then certainly $s\models t\rightarrow u$ and $s\models\neg t\rightarrow\neg u$. So there's no reason to suspect that $s$ is unsatisfiable. Are you sure you've written what you want?

Comment: @Oh yes, I see now, thank you!